# Setting the default JFileChooser directory to a relative path from JAR location

Tags: java, swing

Just a quick summary of what I'm hoping to do:

I currently have a Swing application on a shared folder in my home network (personal use only, so convenience trumps best practices in this case).  This application is a map editor, which I use from a couple different computers in the house, and would also like to use on other computers if I need to work from a different location entirely.

Long story short, I'm trying to find a way to set it up so that, when running the JAR file and opening the file chooser, the JFileChooser defaults to the directory the JAR is in (or even better, a folder within the JARs root folder).  As it is, I can only assign an absolute directory, via the JFileChooser constructor.  I'm doing this now (using the network directory), but would prefer a relative setup.

Is such a thing possible?  I can't shake the feeling I'm doing something wrong, because I imagine this would be a common question, but I can't seem to find it asked anywhere (or rather, I don't see any answers when I search)

Comment: *"I imagine this would be a common question"*  Imagination is a wonderful thing, isn't it?  OTOH, very few people are coding GUIs purely for their own use, and many apps. are installed in places where the user should not browse, while others are deployed in ways in which Oracle feels the installation path is not the business of the application (and will actively hide the path).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the origin of a JAR file from one of the classes in that JAR file using something like this:

```
ProtectionDomain pd = ThatClass.class.getProtectionDomain();
CodeSource cs = pd.getCodeSource();
URL location = cs.getLocation();
```

Comment: Strange that there's no other way, but this should definitely do the trick, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` to get the actual JAR location and then parse it and set it up with `setCurrentDirectory()` for JFileChooser.

Comment: Cool, that's what Krueger said as well.  Thank you both for answering, it's been very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in the code:

```
JFileChooser  fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
```

It sets the default location of the File Chooser as the location of the jar file.